# Which is harder to contract - HIV or AIDS?

Tags: hiv

I am working on mathematically modeling HIV and Tuberculosis Co-infection dynamics, and am working with 12 differential equations describing the behavior of all of the compartments and parameters.

Anyway, I just have one question:

**Which is harder, in general: For a susceptible person to contract HIV, or a HIV+ person to contract AIDS?**

Please pardon my ignorance.

Thanks.

Comment: infection rate constant is much higher than disease progression constant. The rates will depend on how many infected individuals are present and how much are they interacting..

Comment: This is rather broad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question depends hugely on the factors at play.

- The rate of transmission depends on the route of infection.  Wikipedia has a [good breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIV/AIDS#Transmission) showing the wide variability.  Are they getting a blood transfusion?  90%.  Mother-to-infant?  25%.  Male-to-female vaginal sex?  No higher than 0.3%.  Not to mention that the incidence varies massively between countries, as does the most common route of infection.
- The rate of progression to AIDS also depends on a large number of factors including age, viral load, various genotypes, access to medical treatment, and, of course, [long-term nonprogressor (LTNP) status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_nonprogressor).

The incidence of LTNPs is around [1 in 500](http://www.niaid.nih.gov/volunteer/hivlongterm/Pages/default.aspx), or 0.2%, which overlaps with but is at the low end of transmission rates for some routes of infection.